# Folder redirection for multiple locations

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, folder-redirection

I need to find a way to redirect a folder at one location to the file server at the same location and repeat this for all of the other sites.  So all of the computers at SiteA will redirect to the SiteA File server, SiteB computers to the Site B file server etc, Each site has its own subnet

I would like to avoid having to create a group policy for each site and link it with  group security memberships because it will be fore a lot of sites (500+).

One of my first thoughts would be to create a local variable on each client machine and then use group policy to redirect it using that variable.  I think this would work but I want to see if there is a cleaner solution that will work on any computer within the subnet without having to configure each computer with the local variable with the file server name.

Comment: You could set up a DFS namespace and restricting access to site-local servers only. That way \\dfs-root\folderedirection would always point to the site-local directory.  
  
If you have 500+ sites, you probably even have a DFS.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel mentions you could use a DFS namespace for this, especially useful if you wanted to replicate the same data to each location and have them access it only locally.

If you specifically have a need to map a particular drive to a particular server, the site name the computer is a part of is stored in the registry at:

Syetem\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters
Key: DynamicSiteName

It would be a fairly simple logon script written in your favorite language that determined the value of the current site from the key and then mapped the drive to the required server. Then just assign this logon script domain wide through a single group policy.

Comment: I was thinking about this as well.  Thanks to Daniel and jotap  for the help!